# How to query a mysql user database on a static site that also has wordpress blog post summary on it

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a static website in html and php. In the footer I have a segment that retrieves the 4 most recent blog posts from a wordpress blog that I host in connection to the static site.

The code I use to get the most recent blog posts is

```
<?php
// Include WordPress
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-load.php');query_posts('showposts=4');?>
      <!-- Footer Content -->
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 g-mb-40 g-mb-0--lg">
        <div class="u-heading-v2-3--bottom g-brd-white-opacity-0_8 g-mb-20">
          <h2 class="u-heading-v2__title h6 text-uppercase mb-0">From the Wisdom Tooth</h2>
        </div>
    <?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <article>
          <h3 class="h6 g-mb-2">
        <a class="g-color-white-opacity-0_8 g-color-white--hover" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php $thetitle = $post->post_title; /* or you can use get_the_title() */$getlength = strlen($thetitle);$thelength = 25;echo substr($thetitle, 0, $thelength);if ($getlength > $thelength) echo "...";?></a>
      </h3>
          <div class="small g-color-white-opacity-0_6"><?php echo get_the_date( 'd M Y' ); ?></div>
        </article>

        <hr class="g-brd-white-opacity-0_1 g-my-10">
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

What I am trying to do on the same page is get a list of a few of my users that are stored in a separate mysql database.

I have tried this

```
<?php 
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/staff/config.php');
    $sql = "SELECT `stafffname` FROM `accounts` WHERE active = 1 AND id != (SELECT MIN(id) FROM `accounts`) ORDER BY stafffname ASC";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "" .$row["stafffname"]. ", " ;
        }
    } else {
        echo "";
    }   
    $mysqli->close();
    flush();
    ob_flush();
?>
```

The code to get the users runs before the footer code for the blog post.

But when I do this my page foot does not load and I get an error

> Establishing a database connection to the wordpress site.

I have tried looking up a way around this but cannot seem to get it to work.

Am I missing something or is my syntax wrong or can this not be done?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Does your `'/staff/config.php'` file play a part? Does that interface with WP? Or is it just a simple array of values?

Comment: the staff/config.php is the file that contains the database connection data (the dbname, username, pw, localhost). It should not be interfacing with WP but I feel that that connection creates a WP problem as if I remove that line the WP part works fine, but then I do not get my staff data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. @Kinglish - you inspired my thinking in your comment that WP is maintaining a persistent connection to the blog. Since this is not an active blog page, it is not critical that it updates dynamically.

hence I just did a non wp code based lookup

```
<?php
   $mysqli = new mysqli(localhost, username, password, tablename);
   $sql2 = "SELECT post_title, post_date, guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 4";
   $result2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);
      if($result2->num_rows > 0) 
          {
          while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
            echo '
            <article>
              <h3 class="h6 g-mb-2">
            <a class="g-color-white-opacity-0_8 g-color-white--hover" href="'.$row2['guid'].'">'.$row2['post_title'].'</a>
          </h3>
              <div class="small g-color-white-opacity-0_6">'.date('d M Y', strtotime($row2['post_date'])).'</div>
            </article>

            <hr class="g-brd-white-opacity-0_1 g-my-10">
            
            ';
                    }
                } else 
                {
                echo "No Post Avaliable";
                }
            ?>  

          </div>
          <!-- End Footer Content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like wordpress holds a persistent connection open to the DB. Trying to establish a new connection while that's the case is problematic. There are probably a few solutions availble, but I would recommend doing your database queries first, storing the data and then echoing it back where you want it.

At the top:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/staff/config.php');
    $sql = "SELECT `stafffname` FROM `accounts` WHERE active = 1 AND id != (SELECT MIN(id) FROM `accounts`) ORDER BY stafffname ASC";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $staff = array();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $staff[] = $row["stafffname"];
        }
    }   
    $result->free();
    $mysqli->close();
```

Then down where you need it:

```
echo implode(",", $staff);
```

Comment: Hi @Kinglish,
I tried your recommendation and it still does not load the WP section.
The staff data loads correctly though.

Comment: How would you use AJAX in this case?

Comment: Oh ok I see...im checking it out now

Comment: if you need help with the ajax, let me know